# WiX - requirements to install TO a network share

Tags: wix

I have a program, we'll call it foo.msi that I wrote using WIX.

Users want to be able to install it TO (not from, but TO) a network share.
If you try to change to the network , it will not allow you to select the network drive.

What kind of permissions does a user have to have to install stuff to a network share?

Basically the setup is used to distribute a file spread with some logic behind it.

Are there some WIX parameters we can alter here to allow it with basic read/write capabilities?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer.

```
    <Property Id="WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH" Value="1" />
```

WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEFILEPATH="1" will surpress the drive checking but there is a trick .  You must TYPE IN the path you wish to install to fully.  If you try and change it change the Change Folder dialog you will get the error "installation directory mustbe a local hard drive" .

This is a WiX bug and is scheduled to be fixed in WiX 4.0 - https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/4737 .